# How do I get the previous second folder or the folder with a certian name

Tags: python, directory, path, pathlib

I want to get a certain folder, the name of this is '`certainName'` or it is two folder previous.

```py
myFolder = 'certainName'
myPath = r'C:/Documents/something/certainName/anotherFolder/folder'

p = pathlib.Path(myPath)
print(p.relative_to(*p.parts[-2:]))

# Another way

folder = myPath.split(myFolder)
print(folder[0])
```

What I got

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "model.py", line 26, in <module>
    getPrice(int(sys.argv[1]), int(sys.argv[2]), int(sys.argv[3]))
  File "model.py", line 11, in getPrice
    print(p.relative_to(*p.parts[-2:]))
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\pathlib.py", line 907, in relative_to
    raise ValueError("{!r} does not start with {!r}"
```

What I want

```
'C:/Documents/something/certainName/'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can got it by

```py
from pathlib import Path

myFolder = 'certainName'
myPath = r'C:/Documents/something/certainName/anotherFolder/folder'

p = Path(myPath)
print(p.parent.parent)
```

or

```py
myFolder = 'certainName'
myPath = r'C:/Documents/something/certainName/anotherFolder/folder'

print('/'.join(myPath.split('/')[:-2]))
print(myPath.rsplit('/', maxsplit=2)[0])
```

All of them got

```py
C:/Documents/something/certainName
```